# List of documents via REST - Path interpretation

Tags: rest

This seems like a basic question but I have been going around in circles.

At this URL, our customer has a series of PDFs that I want to access via REST:

```
https://site/Forms/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

I am trying to understand the equivalent REST path to obtain the list of documents that live here.  I was trying this:

```
https://site/Forms/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/Forms')/Files
```

But while I am returned a list of links, they aren't the files.

Also, if I target a specific file, I am told 'Specified value is not supported for the serverRelativeUrl parameter':

```
https://site/Forms/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/Forms/file.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find details of the REST API here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521587(v=office.14).aspx

If Forms is your sub-site then you will need something like:

```
https://site/Forms/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Shared%20Documents
```

Comment: And here for 2013: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385.aspx